# Problem with shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am bit confused with how this shared preference works. I had a sample code from a website based on shared preferences. My problem is, editor.commit() doesn't update immediately. Here is my sample code,

```
 public class PreferencesDemo extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the app's shared preferences
    SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // Get the value for the run counter
    int counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);

    // Update the TextView
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text.setText("This app has been started " + counter + " times.");

    // Increment the counter
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("counter", counter+2);
  editor.apply();

    editor.commit(); // Very important
    text1.setText("This app has been started " + counter + " times.");
}
```

}

As you can see, I have counter whose value I am displaying in the first textView and after the commit statement I am printing the updated value in next TextView. But still both the textviews prints the same default value as '0'. So if I restart the app, both the textviews are updated. 
How to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
for store value in sharePreferences..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Share", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("Value", 1 );
editor.commit();
```

for get value

```
prefs.getInt("Value",0);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing this line `prefs.getInt("Value",0);
`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
editor.putInt("counter", counter+2);
```

with

```
counter+= 2;
editor.putInt("counter", counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the counter again!

so you get the value again from the preferences

anyway apply() method is basically the same as commit() method so you only have to call it once! difference is only that apply method is the new way to commit the changes in a background thread instead of the main thread!!!

```
 public class PreferencesDemo extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Get the app's shared preferences
SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// Get the value for the run counter
int counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0);

// Update the TextView
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
text.setText("This app has been started " + counter + " times.");

// Increment the counter
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("counter", counter+2);
editor.commit(); // Very important
counter = app_preferences.getInt("counter", 0); //ADD THIS LINE!
text1.setText("This app has been started " + counter + " times.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing this line prefs.getInt("Value",0);